# CSS Selector Not Matching

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For the following HTML + CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/Gb3dh/1/):

```
<input class="a" placeholder="here"/>
<input class="b" role="x" placeholder="there"/>
```

...

```
.a, .b {
    font-style: italic;
}

[placeholder] input[role="x"] {
    font-style=normal;
}
```

Why is the "font-style" of "class=b" input italic? I would've expected the second CSS selector( get any item with a placeholder title and where the input has a "title" attribute equal to "x") to be in effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two bugs:

- There's an `=` in `font-style=normal;` where there should be a `:`
- `[placeholder]` shouldn't be before `input[role="x"]`, the way you've done it matches an element with attribute `placeholder` that contains an `input` element with attribute `role="x"`

See the updated JSFiddle (or the code below): http://jsfiddle.net/Gb3dh/5/

```
.a, .b {
    font-style: italic;
}

input[role="x"][placeholder] {
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on my bugs. Isn't `!important` frowned upon though since it violates CSS selector rules?

Comment: @Kevin You have a point there, you can probably leave it out. The code seems to work fine in the JSFiddle without it, regardless of the order of the CSS statements... It's just one of the first things that came to mind.

Comment: !important is not needed here. The input[attr][attr] is more specific (0,0,2,1) than a single class name (0,0,1,0). http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 3):

It should be `input[role="x"][placeholder]`, your current selector would match an element `input[role="x"]` inside an element with `[placeholder]` attribute.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the selector to

```
input[placeholder][role="x"] {
    font-style=normal;
}
```

Your selector means an input with attribute `role="x"` which is inside a element with attribute `placeholder`